# Show that $nP(X\le n)-n\to0$ when $n\to+\infty$, or not necessarily

Tags: probability

$\lim_{n\to\infty} (nP(X\le n)-n)=0$ where $X\in \mathbb{N}$. This seems like it could be true, but at the same time it seems like it probably is not, just knowing what I know about limits.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly why I thought it should probably be true, but if $\lim{\n\to\infty}P(x\le n)$ goes to $1$ really slowly could this limit still technically get to $-\infty$? This is always the part of analysis I am always slightly uncomfortable with.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $P(x\geq n) = \min (1,\frac{1}{n^\alpha})$, i.e. $P(x\leq n) = \max(0,1-\frac{1}{n^\alpha})$. Then for large $n$ the equality below holds,

$$nP(x\leq n) - n = nP(x\geq n) = \frac{1}{n^{\alpha-1}}→ \begin{cases} ∞ & \alpha < 1 \\ 1 & \alpha = 1 \\ 0 & \alpha > 1\end{cases}$$

Comment: Ok yeah, I also got a counterexample if you consider $P(x\ge n)=1-\frac{1}{n}$. So I guess it is not true.

Answer (score 1):

This is false in general: first, the expression in the limit can be rewritten as the negative of
$$ n(1-P(x\leqslant n)) = n P(x > n) $$
It should be easy to see that, for example, taking
$$ P(x > n) = \frac{1}{n^{\alpha}}, \quad n=2,3,\dotsc,  $$
(which is obviously a legitimate distribution since CDF will be positive, increasing and tend to $1$) if $0<\alpha<1$, then the limit does not exist.

On the other hand, suppose the expectation is finite. Then
$$ E[X] = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k P(x=k) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{k} P(x=k) = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=m}^{\infty} P(x=k) = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} P(x \geqslant k)<\infty, $$
so if we don't have $\lim_{n \to \infty} n P(x \geqslant n)=0$, the sum diverges. Hence a sufficient condition for the limit to be zero is that the expectation be finite.

(On the other hand, the limit existing is not sufficient for the expectation to be finite: consider $1/(n\log{n})$.)